# Problem compiling Cypress software with IAR

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, cypress, iar

I've a Cypress BLE module and have compilation problem with IAR.
In "ezsapi.h" are defined this macros:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    /* standard GNU C */
    #ifdef _WIN32
        /* MinGW, Cygwin, TDM-GCC, etc. */
        #define __PACKDEF(STRUCTNAME, STRUCTDEF) typedef struct STRUCTDEF __attribute__((__packed__,gcc_struct)) STRUCTNAME
    #else
        /* generic gcc */
        #define __PACKDEF(STRUCTNAME, STRUCTDEF) typedef struct STRUCTDEF __attribute__((__packed__)) STRUCTNAME
    #endif
    #define ALIGNED __attribute__((aligned(0x4)))
#else
    /* Microsoft Visual C++ */
    #define __PACKDEF(STRUCTNAME, STRUCTDEF) __pragma(pack(push, 1)) STRUCTDEF __pragma(pack(pop)) STRUCTNAME
    #define ALIGNED
#endif
```

IAR usually use **#pragma pack(push,1)** and **#pragma pack(pop)** and I tryed to modify the macro in:

```
#define __PACKDEF(STRUCTNAME, STRUCTDEF) #pragma(pack(push, 1)) STRUCTDEF #pragma(pack(pop)) STRUCTNAME
```

With original macros the errors reported is:

```
ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe020]: identifier "pack" is undefined
ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe018]: expected a ")" ezsapi.h(694) :
Error[Pe079]: expected a type specifier ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe260]:
explicit type is missing ("int" assumed) ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe141]:
unnamed prototyped parameters not allowed when body is present
ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe130]: expected a "{"
```

and with my macro the errors reported is:

```
(69 is the line where the macro is located)
ezsapi.h(69) : Error[Pe052]: expected a macro parameter name
ezsapi.h(69) : Error[Pe052]: expected a macro parameter name
ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe020]: identifier "pack" is undefined
ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe018]: expected a ")" ezsapi.h(694) :
Error[Pe079]: expected a type specifier ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe260]:
explicit type is missing ("int" assumed) ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe141]:
unnamed prototyped parameters not allowed when body is present
ezsapi.h(694) : Error[Pe130]: expected a "{"
```

What's the correct formula for IAR?
What's escaping me?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: Symbols starting with __ (such as __PACKDEF) are reserved by the C-standard for internal use by the compiler and its runtime library and should never be declared or defined by user code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of solving this problem. My suggestion is that you use the `__packed` type attibute instead of `#pragma pack()` as this has a more well defined meaning. This, however, needs IAR language extensions to be switched on. If you can't enable language extensions or for some other reason need to use pack-pragma you have to use an alternative pragma syntax to be able to include it in a preprocessor macro. If you use `_Pragma("pack(push,1)")` and `_Pragma("pack(pop)")` you macro should work as expected. Definitions of PACKDEF for both alternatives are shown below:

```
#define PACKDEF(STRUCTNAME, STRUCTDEF) typedef __packed struct STRUCTDEF STRUCTNAME

#define PACKDEF(STRUCTNAME, STRUCTDEF)  _Pragma("pack(push,1)") typedef struct STRUCTDEF STRUCTNAME _Pragma("pack(pop)")
```

Comment: Hi Johan and thanks for your help.
I tried your solution, but doesn't work.
In reality, __PACKDEF is defined and used only into ezsapi.h and there are more definitions like this that generate errors:
__PACKDEF(uint8a_t,
{
    uint8_t length;
    uint8_t data[EZS_UINT8A_ACTUAL_MAX];
});

Comment: #define PACKDEF(STRUCTNAME, STRUCTDEF)  _Pragma("pack(push,1)") typedef struct STRUCTDEF STRUCTNAME _Pragma("pack(pop)") Works fine.
Many thanks.

Comment: @Stefano If you found the answer useful it would be nice if you marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I accepted it. Excuse me, but I'm newbe of StackOverflow.